# How to obtain new access token without login laravel sanctum?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, sanctum

I made a login api using Laravel Sanctum for the front end, the token only expires for 15 minutes.  If it expires, the front end user must log back in to get a new token. For reactjs developer, how do you get a new token without having to log in again?

Comment: SetInterval every 14m with an ajax call retrieving a new token..

Comment: what if user leave the page? if so they are required to login again @ml59

Comment: you can check if the user is active before doing the call. Here is a nice package https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js